# Express square root in terms of log 10

Tags: exponentiation

I’m trying to help my son with some revision. One of his revision questions uses a formula $$T(n) = 4T(n^\frac{1}{2}) + \log_{10} n$$
To solve the problem he needs to express the $n^\frac{1}{2}$ in the form $\frac{n}{b}$. There’s a hint to define $k = \log_{10} n$, but I’m struggling to see how this helps. Is there a way to rewrite that square root of n using log? I’ve tried expanding it in different ways, but I think I’m missing something fundamental

Answer (score 1):

If
$T(n) = 4T(n^\frac{1}{2}) + \log_{10} n
$,
let
$n=2^{2^m}$
so that
$2^m=\log_2(n)
$.

This works because
$(2^{2^m})^{1/2}
=2^{2^m/2}
=2^{2^{m-1}}
$.

Then

$T(2^{2^m}) 
= 4T((2^{2^m})^\frac{1}{2}) + \log_{10} 2^{2^m}
= 4T(2^{2^{m-1}}) + 2^m\log_{10} 2
$.

Now,
let
$U(m)
=T(2^{2^m})
$.
This becomes
$U(m)
=4U(m-1)+\log_2(m)\log_{10}(2)
=4U(m-1)+\log_{10}(m)
$.

You should be able to solve this
for $U$.

Then replace $m$
by $2^{2^m}$
to get $T$.